# openssl aes256 encryption of a file

Tags: c, encryption, cryptography, openssl, aes

I'd like to encrypt a file with aes256 using OpenSSL with C.
I did find a pretty nice example [here](http://saju.net.in/blog/?p=36).

Should I first read the whole file into a memory buffer and than do the aes256, or should I do it partial with a ~16K buffer?

Any snippets or hints?

Comment: Is this part of a larger project, or do you really only want to encrypt a file?

Comment: it's part of a larger project. I'd like to encrypt backup files. My approach is to do a AES256 with a random generated key and then do a RSA async. public key crypto over the random generated AES key. You know what i mean?

Comment: Yeah, makes sense. I never used openssl for that (I found libmcrypt to be very good for symmetric encryption), but if you need the PKI stuff, I'm sure you're using the right tool. Buffered mode is the way to go, and I'm sure you'll find some tutorials or examples on the internet...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Loading the whole file in a buffer can get inefficient to impossible on larger files - do this only if all your files are below some size limit.

OpenSSL's EVP API (which is also used by [the example you linked](http://saju.net.in/blog/?p=36)) has an `EVP_EncryptUpdate` function, which can be called multiple times, each time providing some more bytes to encrypt. Use this in a loop together with reading in the plaintext from a file into a buffer, and writing out the ciphertext to another file (or the same one). (Analogously for decryption.)

Of course, instead of inventing a new file format (which you are effectively doing here), think about implementing the OpenPGP Message format ([RFC 4880](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880)). There are less chances to make mistakes which might destroy your security  – and as an added bonus, if your program somehow ceases to work, your users can always use the standard tools (PGP or GnuPG) to decrypt the file.

Comment: i was also thinking of GPG. But the problem is i could not found any library which does the work for me (like just de/encrypt files with openPGP).
Do you know any library?
Of course i could pipe trough GPG,... but my goal is also to be portable to windows. So a c/c++ lib would be best.

Comment: I didn't say to use a library to do this, just to reimplement the same format (using OpenSSL like you intended). If you need a GPG-library, have a look at [GPGME (GnuPG Made Easy)](http://www.gnupg.org/related_software/gpgme/). (If I understand right, you still have to deliver GPG with your application to use this.)

Answer (score 5):

It's better to reuse a fixed buffer, unless you know you'll **always** process small files - but I don't think that fits your *backup* files definition.

I said **better** in a non-cryptographic way :-) There won't be any difference at the end (for the encrypted file) but your computer might not like (or even be able) to load several MB (or GB) into memory.

Crypto-wise the operations are done in block, for **AES** it's 128 bits (16 bytes). So, for simplicity, you better use a multiple of 16 bytes for your buffer. Otherwise the choice is yours. *I would suggest between 4kb to 16kb buffers but, to be honest, I would test several values.*